# Not able to select drop-down values in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Not able to select drop-down values in selenium.

HTML code is:

This code used to select - Select Customer -

```
<div id="createTasksPopup_customerSelector" class="customerOrProjectSelector selectorWithPlaceholderContainer at-dropdown-list-btn-ct notSelected">
    <table id="ext-comp-1057" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn at-dropdown-list-btn x-btn-over x-btn-focus" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: auto;">
       <tbody>
             <tr id="ext-gen397" class=" x-btn-with-menu">
                  <td class="x-btn-left">
                      <td class="x-btn-center">
                          <em unselectable="on">
                              <button id="ext-gen391" class="x-btn-text" type="button">- Select Customer -</button>
                          </em>
                      </td>
                 <td class="x-btn-right">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now i need to select - ALL ACTIVE CUSTOMERS -

```
<div id="ext-gen613" class="x-layer x-menu at-dropdown-list-btn-menu customerProjectListSelector customerListSelector createTasksCustomerProjectSelector" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: visible; left: 360px; top: 163px;">
    <a id="ext-gen616" class="x-menu-focus" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false;" href="#"/>
        <ul id="ext-gen617" class="x-menu-list">
            <li id="ext-gen621" class="x-menu-list-item ">
            <li id="ext-gen623" class="x-menu-list-item ">
            <li id="ext-gen625" class="x-menu-list-item x-menu-item-active">
                <a id="ext-gen626" class="x-menu-item" href="#">
                    <img class="x-menu-item-icon " src="/img/default/extjs/s.gif?hash=970179041"/>
                        - ALL ACTIVE CUSTOMERS -
                </a>
            </li>
        <li id="ext-gen627" class="x-menu-list-item ">
</ul>
```

[image]

**Code**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("selectCustomer_XPATH")))‌​.click();
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOW‌​N).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: My Code is:driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("selectCustomer_XPATH"))).click();
    
 
 Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 
 act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
 
 Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: It's look like a `ExtJs` component... you could select value from dropdown with using java script if you have some idea about `ExtJs` because it's a menu in extJs and in their library they are provides function to select it

Comment: Firstly just execute this `Ext.getCmp("ext-comp-1057")` in your browser console and let me know what are you getting...

Answer (score 0):

All the selections in the fake dropdown are `A` tags. You should be able to click to open the dropdown and then click the `A` that contains the desired text. Try the code below.

```
String searchText = "- ALL ACTIVE CUSTOMERS -";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("selectCustomer_XPATH"))).click();
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#ext-gen617 a"));
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    // this may need to be .contains() instead of .equals()
    if (link.getText().trim().equals(searchText))
    {
        link.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

---

NOTE: If the id's are dynamic, I can't tell what to change it to without seeing the page and being able to refresh a few times and see what changes and what doesn't. I would start by editing the CSS selector. Maybe try a few of the below and see if any work.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.customerProjectListSelector a"));
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.customerListSelector a"));
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.createTasksCustomerProjectSelector a"));
```

Comment: hi driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#ext-gen617 a")); here "#ext-gen617 a" is dynamically changing how to handle those... right now i'm able to select to select customer only.

Comment: I updated the answer for a couple things to try but without seeing the page, I'm not sure what else to try without more info.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to below approach:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("createTasksPopup_customerSelector"))); 
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("- ALL ACTIVE CUSTOMERS -");
```

**Note:-** You can also use `xpath` instead of `Id` .

Let me know if you face any issue.